# Why 1/2*2 is 1 and not 0.25 in Python since python follows PEDMAS?

Tags: python-3.x

I know BODMAS and recently I have started with Python which follows PEDMAS.
So, really trivial question - why 1/2* 2 is 1 and not 0.25?

Comment: PEMDAS, PEDMAS, BEDMAS, BODMAS, and all of these acronyms are all exactly the same order of operation. Type the same expression into a calculator and you will also get 1. In the common order of operations, the answer is generally not 1/4, even though you may read "1/2*2" to yourself as "1/(2*2)", that's not what you've written. This is why in mathematics the division symbol and / are not used, because they are ambiguous, and fractions are written instead. To avoid headache, always use parenthesis around the numerator and denominator wherever its possibly ambiguous while programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication and division have the same priority and are executed from left to right. For example, I punched "PEDMAS" into my favorite search engine and [my first hit](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-pemdas-definition-rule-examples.html) said:

> Even though M for multiplication in PEMDAS comes before D for division, these two operations actually have the same priority. Complete only those two operations in the order they occur from left to right.